# Testing security tools for non-standard protocols

Tags: penetration-test

Many security solutions like firewalls, IPSs and Proxies are fully prepared for TCP and sometimes UDP, but what about non-standard protocol types like IGMP, CAOS, VISA and others. The whole https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers is a potential vector.

What is the best way to test those solutions for protection of evasion  over those non-standard protocols? I would take any response with a commercial product but specially any tools that I can build my own.

Comment: Anything unknown can just be dropped...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for nmap ([IP Protocol scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html)) or [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html). Older tools such as [isic](http://isic.sf.net) or [ip6sic](http://ip6sic.sf.net) are in the same class, as are point-commercial solutions such as Codenomicon or Beyond Security and big players like Spirent and Ixia.

Probably my favorite tool for working with non-HTTP/TLS traffic (for those protocols, I'd use Burp Suite Professional) is [Canape](https://www.contextis.com/services/research/canape/). Canape is a pluggable proxy, so I can record packets and frames in order to play with them. If I really wanted to hire a firm to help with testing security appliances, I'd look at Deja vu Security for their [Peach Fuzzing Framework](http://www.dejavusecurity.com/peach-fuzzer/) intellectual property, instructional capital, and thought leadership.